# How can I add my own generated code to my android project (in Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have a pattern that I have been using a lot recently in my apps for as a way to map an Enum value to some resource. So instead of using switches in my code, I can simply ask for "The primary text colour for MyStateEnum.ACTIVE" or some such.

Right now I'm converting the full name of some enum (com.example.app.MyStateEnum.ACTIVE) into a resource name (`com_example_app_mystateenum_active`) and appending the "name" of the thing I want (`primary_text_color`) and then running that through `getResources().getIdentifier(enumName+"_"+thingName, "color", getPackageName())` to give me the id I need to fetch the resource I want.

However `getIdentifier()` is slow compared to using `R.color.com_example_app_mystateenum_active_primary_text_color` so I'd like to find a better way.

I think that better way is to generate code *in the exact same way R is generated* so that I can more easily access the the ids. I'm thinking that something like this will work:

colors.xml:

```
<color name="some_name" 
   ex:use="primary_text_color"
   ex:value="com.example.app.MyStateEnum.ACTIVE">#FF00FF</color>
<color name="some_name_default"
   ex:use="primary_text_color">#FF0000</color>
```

something.java

```
int activeColor = getResources().getColor(X.color.primary_text_color.getForEnum(MyStateEnum.ACTIVE)); //#FF00FF
int activeColor = getResources().getColor(X.color.primary_text_color.getForEnum(MyStateEnum.INACTIVE)); //#FF0000
```

(I hate picking names, but you get the idea). I would *like* to have those values automatically updated like `R` is as well.

My problem is that I'm having a hard time finding *anything* suggesting where I should start.  I'm not sure if its a matter of "you're asking the wrong question" or "no one has wanted to do this before so start reading the source code for the android plugin".

Comment: Gradle for Android took this from "the next best thing to impossible" to merely "something that few people on the planet need", which is why you're not finding a lot written about it. Also, a custom Gradle plugin may be contingent upon the Gradle for Android object model, which is only now stabilizing as it heads towards 1.0. You may want to poke around to see who else has created such plugins (check the Android Arsenal) and see how they're doing what they're doing. You could also ponder if an annotation processor might be a solution.

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't considered annotations, I'll take a look. My only issue would be that your annotations would need to know all the ways its used, which would limit code reuse (but really, that might not matter so much except to my over developed sense of perfection).